# My own answer was double-posted while inline editing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editing

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/309894/how-to-make-cmddelete-delete-a-line-left-of-the-cursor-in-firefox/310003#310003), I already had an answer, but decided to edit it and add some clarification.

While I was editing, the "1 new answer has been posted" message appeared on top of the page, but I just continued editing.

When I was finished, I saw that my **original answer was still there**, and now I had two answers, one being the first (unedited) one, the other one my edited version.

- This is the [original answer](https://superuser.com/questions/309894/how-to-make-cmddelete-delete-a-line-left-of-the-cursor-in-firefox/310001#310001) (> 10k only)
- This is [the edited one](https://superuser.com/questions/309894/how-to-make-cmddelete-delete-a-line-left-of-the-cursor-in-firefox/310003#310003).

There is no sign of me editing the answer though.

<sub>I use Chrome 14, and while editing I always stayed in the same page, i.e. didn't close the tab or refreshed before.</sub>

Comment: FYI: If the inline editing is (currently) broken for you, then a `Ctrl`+click or middle-click on `edit` should open the old editor in a new tab for you. Not ideal, but better than duping stuff.

Comment: I don't answer much these days, but before that happens again, I'll probably do so. I can't try to reproduce though -- do we have a "playground" question here on SE?

Comment: There is the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/) on MSO, but it's pretty crowded (and really for formatting). Personally I see no harm in you self-answering on this question to test if this can be reproduced.

Comment: Well, if it can't be reproduced, it was just a hiccup or some tiny JavaScript AJAX thing. I'll just leave it here if somebody wants to inspect it in the future.

Comment: leaving it as no-repro for now. if anyone can repro will be happy to fix

Comment: @SamSaffron Okay, I shall get back to you if it ever happens again!

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's see if I can reproduce this!

*Update:* Doesn't seem so.